# Unknown type name 'FIRDatabaseReference'

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase

I am trying to use Firebase in an iOS app.

I installed what I needed following the instructions given here:
`Add Firebase to your iOS app` right after login into Firebase.
Adding these lines:

```
@import UIKit;
@import Firebase;
```

(At this point the app keeps compiling and working as usual)

Later I followed the instructions given here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/
in order to start working with a database.

Now is when I hit a problem; this line:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) FIRDatabaseReference *ref;
```

Brings this error message from the compiler:

```
Unknown type name 'FIRDatabaseReference'
Property with 'retain (or strong)' attribute must be of object type
```

Since I have only been following the documentation I do not quite understand why the type is unknown here.
Any relevant tip would be very useful.

Comment: Make sure `'Firebase/Database'` pod is installed in your project workspace.

Comment: Indeed, I had correctly updated the pod file, but forgot to run pod install after. Thanks for pointing out the right spot. I fixed that, now it works. (For some reason I am not able to upvote your comment though I want),

Answer (score 3):

Make sure following pods are installed in your project workspace

```
target 'FirebaseSDK' do
    pod 'Firebase/Core'
    pod 'Firebase/Auth'
    pod 'Firebase/Database'
    pod 'Firebase/Storage'
end
```

And then import SDK like as

```
#import <Firebase/Firebase.h>
```